# What properties of lattice are preserved in a weak lattice structure

Tags: lattice-theory

A lattice structure requires that every two elements have a join and a meet.
Suppose we consider instead posets in which for every two elements $x,y$, if there exists an element greater than both of them, then their join exists, and if there exists an element less than both of them, then their meet exists. What can be said about such posets?

Thanks

Comment: I took my best guess as to what the question was asking. Of course Bjørn's answer shows that in some sense the question is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

These structures can be characterized as being exactly what you obtain from bounded lattices by removing their top and bottom elements.